# The missing .a file on iOS project

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

Having check [manual linking -- step 2](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#step-2-1), it says the .a file should linking to react-native, but when I check my iOS project it can not be found, how to create it or other alternative to choice?

Answer (score 2):

you should upgrade your project like this:

`Step 1 : Delete your ios folder (And the android if you want) of your project directory`

Do this commands :

`Step 2 : react-native upgrade`

`Step 2 : react-native link`

`Step 2 : react-native run-ios //or// react-native run-android`

This would Init platform specific projects and i hope be your solution

good luck

Comment: My bad, the original mean of this issue is said that other local iOS project (not the react-native iOS project) is missing the .a file, and now I want to make this local iOS a static library linking to react native. Always thank for nice responding.